# How do I create year based means of individual data for countries in a data.frame?

Tags: r

I'm dealing with a somewhat big dataframe with 341k observations and 1.4k variables. The observations contain individual data for various countries over several years. I now want to create the year based means of individual data for each country:

```
set.seed(42)
ctry <- c(rep("AU", 6),rep("BY", 6),rep("CH", 6),rep("DE", 6))
year <- c(rep(2001,2),rep(2002,2),rep(2003,2),rep(2001,2),rep(2002,2),rep(2003,2),
      rep(2001,2),rep(2002,2),rep(2003,2),rep(2001,2),rep(2002,2),rep(2003,2))
a <- rnorm(24,1,.1)
b <- rnorm(24,2,.2)
c <- rnorm(24,3,.3)
(df <- data.frame(ctry,year,a,b,c))
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25900795/how-do-i-create-a-column-of-means-of-specific-columns-in-a-data-frame) matching my problem and **Peter Lustig** gave a great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25900795/how-do-i-create-a-column-of-means-of-specific-columns-in-a-data-frame). For myself I came to a solution with the `ave()` function but it's quite inconvenient for 1.4k variables:

```
df1 <- df
df1$mean.a <- ave(df[[3]], df[[2]], df[[1]])
df1$mean.b <- ave(df[[4]], df[[2]], df[[1]])
df1$mean.c <- ave(df[[5]], df[[2]], df[[1]])
(df2 <- unique(df1[,c(1,2,(ncol(df1)-2):ncol(df1))]))
```

**akrun's** [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25900795/how-do-i-create-a-column-of-means-of-specific-columns-in-a-data-frame) looks promising but I was not able to fit it for me. Maybe there's a more neat solution? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the OP's output with `ave`, it seems like we are grouping by the same columns and get the `mean` of other columns.  So, instead of using `ave` we need to `summarise` by group.  This can be done with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(ctry, year) %>% 
   summarise_at(.vars = names(df)[3:5], funs(Mean = mean))
```

---

Or if we need to get the `mean` of all variables except the grouping variables, as @StevenBeaupre suggested, we can use `summarise_all`

```
df %>% 
   group_by(ctry, year) %>% 
   summarise_all(mean)
#    ctry  year         a        b        c
#   <fctr> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1      AU  2001 1.0403130 2.146472 3.033630
#2      AU  2002 1.0497996 1.797957 2.930713
#3      AU  2003 1.0149072 1.982010 3.332794
#4      BY  2001 1.0708431 2.116029 3.054947
#5      BY  2002 1.0977855 2.042618 3.115368
#6      BY  2003 1.1795758 1.878795 2.593769
#7      CH  2001 0.9166175 1.836463 2.972699
#8      CH  2002 1.0251315 1.762191 3.297234
#9      CH  2003 0.8529646 1.984494 3.086288
#10     DE  2001 0.9439823 2.003146 3.206153
#11     DE  2002 0.8956026 1.906454 3.246241
#12     DE  2003 1.0521379 2.063271 2.830004
```

---

For convenience, we can also wrap this in a function making use of `quosures` from the devel version of `dplyr`

```
fMean <- function(dat, grp1, grp2, otherVars){
    #enquo does similar functionality as substitute from base R
    grp1 <- enquo(grp1) 
    grp2 <- enquo(grp2)

    dat %>%
       #evaluate the quosure by unquote (UQ or !!)
       group_by(!!grp1, !!grp2) %>%
       summarise_at(.vars = otherVars, funs(Mean = mean))


} 

fMean(df, ctry, year, names(df)[3:5])
#     ctry  year    a_Mean   b_Mean   c_Mean
#   <fctr> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1      AU  2001 1.0403130 2.146472 3.033630
#2      AU  2002 1.0497996 1.797957 2.930713
#3      AU  2003 1.0149072 1.982010 3.332794
#4      BY  2001 1.0708431 2.116029 3.054947
#5      BY  2002 1.0977855 2.042618 3.115368
#6      BY  2003 1.1795758 1.878795 2.593769
#7      CH  2001 0.9166175 1.836463 2.972699
#8      CH  2002 1.0251315 1.762191 3.297234
#9      CH  2003 0.8529646 1.984494 3.086288
#10     DE  2001 0.9439823 2.003146 3.206153
#11     DE  2002 0.8956026 1.906454 3.246241
#12     DE  2003 1.0521379 2.063271 2.830004
```

---

In addition to `dplyr`, we can also use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, mean), .(ctry, year)]
```

Here, `setDT`, converts the 'data.frame' to `data.table`, grouped by 'ctry', 'year', we loop through the columns of Subset of Data.table and get the `mean`.  If we need to get only the `mean` of specific column, specify it in `.SDcols`

```
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, mean), .(ctry, year), .SDcols = a:c]
```

Or `base R` with `aggregate`

```
aggregate(.~ctry + year, df, mean)
```

Comment: I get the `Error: .cols should be a character/numeric vector or a columns object`

Comment: @jaySf  I am using the `devel` version of `dplyr` (soon to be released 0.6.0`. what is the version you have

Comment: I have `dplyr` 0.5.0. `summarise_at` didn't work, but `summarise_all` did! I'm looking forward for 0.6.0, looks great!

Comment: @jaySf  You can download the devel version from github i.e. `https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr` and use `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")`  I added the data.table and base R methods